# Angular - How to display data from a array that contains arrays?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to display some data from a array that has arrays in it, but it just keeps giving me the error;

[image]

I have tried using keyvaule, but that hasn't seemed to of helped.

This is the response im getting from a api

```
{
  "answers": [
    {
      "questions": [
        "Whats the weather like today?"
      ],
      "answer": "Sunny",
      "score": 100,
      "id": 1,
    }
  ],
}
```

and this is the html I have currently

```html
<li *ngFor="let result of searchData | keyvalue">
    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title uk-margin-remove" >{{result.answers.questions}}</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">
        <p>{{ result.answers.answer }}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is what my component looks like;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FaqModel } from '../_core/models/faq.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq',
  templateUrl: './faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq.component.css']
})
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {
  snapshotParam = "initial value";
  subscribedParam = "initial value";
  API_TOPIC = 'URL';
  API_FAQ = 'URL';
  topics = [];
  asideData: any;
  faqData: any;
  API_SEARCH = 'URL';
  searchData: any;

  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.subscribedParam = params.get("id");
    });
    this.http.get<AsideModel[]>(this.API_TOPIC).subscribe(data => {
      this.asideData = data;
    });
  }

  goto(id: string): void {
    this.http.get<FaqModel>('URL' + id).subscribe(faqData => {
      this.faqData = faqData;
    });
  }

  postSearch(){
    this.http.post<any>(this.API_SEARCH,{question:'Whats the weather like today?'}).subscribe(searchData => {
      this.searchData = searchData;
    });
 }

}
interface AsideModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  lastPublishedTimestamp: string;
  language: string;
}
```

I would like {{ result.answers.questions }} to display the question,
and for {{ result.answers.answer }} to display the answer

Comment: You want to loop through "answers" array?

Comment: Actually searchData  is null, the error comes from the API try by using a debugger or a console log to print the searchData  in the subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all, you don't need to use `keyvalue` pipe.

Just loop trough `response.answers` with `ngForOf`

```
<li *ngFor="let answer of searchData.answers">
    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title uk-margin-remove" >{{ answer.questions.join(', ') }}</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">
        <p>{{ answer.answer }}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

`answer.questions` it's array so you need loop trough the `questions` and display each entity. Or you can aggregate array to single value and display it (as shown above)

Comment: Would you know why I would be getting this error after trying out your solution? https://i.imgur.com/xgrIF00.png

Comment: I've updated my original post to include my component, isn't searchData defined? Or have I done that wrong?

Comment: You get undefined because the API call hasn't returned when the component is rendered. Use the safe navigation operator:  `searchData?.answers`.